# How to show tooltips when hovering over floating-action-button using Material CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design, material-ui

**background:** I need to redesign a legacy system.  One thing that this system has is an awful layout so as part of my goal is to improve the overall user experience.  As part of that I am using floating-action-buttons (FAB).  One thing about the FAB is that it is fairly new to UX design, so its adaption will be a hurdle.

**Problem:** In order to help with adaption of my design I want to implement a FAB that shows materialcss tooltips for each action button while hovering over the *main*  floating button.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution on my own, I hope this helps somebody out. One thing that is semi-important is that the jquery needs to be sourced in before the material js.

**HTML:**

```
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <div class="fixed-action-btn">
      <a id="fab-btn" class="btn-floating btn-large red">
        <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="btn-floating red tooltipped" data-position="left" data-tooltip="I am a tooltip"><i class="material-icons">insert_chart</i></a></li>
        <li><a class="btn-floating yellow darken-1 tooltipped" data-position="left" data-tooltip="I am a tooltip"><i class="material-icons">format_quote</i></a></li>
        <li><a class="btn-floating green tooltipped" data-position="left" data-tooltip="I am a tooltip"><i class="material-icons">publish</i></a></li>
        <li><a class="btn-floating blue tooltipped" data-position="left" data-tooltip="I am a tooltip"><i class="material-icons">attach_file</i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.fixed-action-btn').floatingActionButton();
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tooltipped').tooltip();
});

$("#fab-btn").mouseover(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.tooltipped').tooltip('open');

},600); 
});
$("#fab-btn").mouseout(function(){
    $('.tooltipped').tooltip('close');
})
```

Live Demo: [jsfiddle.net/1oz2ucty](http://jsfiddle.net/1oz2ucty)